# Add string to all looped items except the last one

Tags: php, mysql, string

I'm looping through some mysql results and need to add `<span id=bottom></span>` to each of them except the last row. What's the easiest way of doing this?

Will I have to count rows and then use a counter and an if/else statement? Or is there an easier method?

Comment: The id field in html should be unique.  consider class or name instead.

Comment: is javascript or jquery an option?

Comment: what do you mean with add html to each of them? 
Are they in a row just fetched? 
Are they in several rows and you have to append a field to every row?
Are several row and you have to wrap each of them?
Have you to wrap all the results in a single span (and this explain the id) but the last?
Please, be more clear.

Comment: We don't have a [mcve] here.  This question is Unclear.  Do you need the row values to be wrapped in the span or should the span follow each iteration?  Is it a separator?  As Hogan said, it should be a class, not an id.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  $list[] = $row;
}
$lastItem = array_pop($list);
foreach($list as $item) {
  echo sprintf('<span id="bottom">%s</span>', $item['value']);
}
// do something with the last item..
```

Not very short, but that would do the trick. Alternatively you could do what you suggested:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);
for($i = 0; $i < $num-1; $i++) {
  $element = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  // echo here..
}
$item = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // fetch last item..
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: Deleted my answer since yours was the same but you posted first. :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert, but can you put each row in an array?  That way to know the length and you can loop through the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$list = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  $list[] = $row;

foreach(array_slice($list, 0, -1) as $item) {
  echo sprintf('<span id="bottom">%s</span>', $item['value']);
}
// do something with the last item..
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation. `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` in any code for any reason -- it should be `printf()` every time.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid copying all the data before processing it if you fetch a record in advance before printing it (or the other way round: process the previously fetched record)

```
foreach( $pdo->query('SELECT x FROM foo') as $r) {
  if ( isset($row) ) {
    echo '<span>', $row['x'], '</span>';
  }
  $row = $r;
}
if ( isset($row) ) {
  echo $row['x'];
}
```